# Input as number in JavaScript prompt

Tags: javascript

Can we customize a prompt box in JavaScript so it takes time as input?

```
var r = prompt("ENTER THE NUMBER OF SECONDS AFTER WHICH YOU WANT TO BE REMINDED");
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you include in OP?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

Comment: At best, you can validate user input and if not only numbers, redisplay a new prompt. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#Notes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No you can't customize the built-in browser prompt for security reasons.

Your best bet is to use a JavaScript library which offers such a feature like [SweetAlert](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/)

You can create a number prompt like this:

```
swal({
    input: 'number',
    title: 'Enter a number',
}).then(function(result){
    alert("You picked number " + result.value);
});
```

Alternatively you could verify the user's input yourself and stick with prompt like this:

```
// need a way to check if input is a valid number
var isNumber = Number.isInteger || function(number){ return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n) }

var result = prompt("Enter your number");
if (!isNumber(result)){
   prompt("Please try again and enter your number");
}
```

I would strongly advice against using prompts as the user's browser will most likely block too many prompts in a row. Also keep in mind that the native prompt will block every other interaction a user can make with your side, you don't receive events and your UI won't update. Your website basically freezes until a user interacts with said prompt/alert/confirm.

Comment: "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." :P

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to enforce data formats in a vanilla prompt as e.g. in a HTML5 `input` field.

You could achieve that by using a library like alertifyjs, which allows you to customize prompts.

Answer (score 0):

The *prompt method* returns *string*

But we can still convert these string numbers into type Numbers by simply using

***Number() or parseInt()***

var r= Number(prompt("ENTER THE NUMBER OF SECONDS AFTER WHICH YOU WANT TO BE REMINDED"));

This will return Number type prompt value.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe some beginner code will help

```
function input() {
   var n = Number(prompt("ENTER THE NUMBER OF SECONDS AFTER WHICH YOU WANT TO BE REMINDED"));
   if (isNaN(n)) //Check what number it is
       return input();
   }

   input(); // Your prompt 
}
```

Comment: This is an endless loop and most likely not what OP needs. Also most browsers will block this after the third attempt.